# scanning /etc/passwd with grep

Tags: unix, grep

I am trying to use a single command to scan /etc/passwd for the gecos field in the format "User (userid) is (Real name)" so output would be "User brian is Brian". I have been trying for a good hour and cannot come up with a good solution. I'm sure i need to use grep but cannot figure out a good way to do it.

Comment: Is that not a job for `awk` (or Perl, Python, ...)?

Comment: Yeah that could be.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F: '$1=="brian" {print "User", $1, "is", $8}' /etc/passwd
```

Leave out the `$1=="brian"` if you want to print every line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

awk -F : '{print "User ", $1, "is ", $5;}' /etc/passwd

Using awk seems to be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Per Pascal's comment you'll need to use a utility like awk (or Perl, Python, Ruby, etc).  This awk command will work for passwd files with comma-separated GECOS fields with the user's real name first:

```
awk -F: '{split($5,a,","); print "User "$1" is "a[1]}' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but all the answers thus far solve the problem of parsing the passwd line into your format. However, your suggestion for using `grep` makes me think you are interested in also picking a specific entry rather than printing out a line for every user on the system.

`grep` is certainly one possibility for this, but I find the `getent` command to be a cleaner way to get entries from the passwd file.

Since there are so many `awk` based solutions, I have attempted to do the parsing with `sed` in stead. This is merely to have a more colourful set of answers, I would not consider it better or simpler for the task.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# != 1 ]]; then
    echo "$0: wrong number of arguments"
    echo -n "Usage: "
    echo "$0 {username | UID}"
fi

getent passwd "$1" \
    | sed 's/\(.*\):.*:.*:.*:\(.*\):.*:.*$/User \1 is \2/'
```

Extending the script to take an arbitrary number of arguments is left an exercise for the reader.